# unable to call public API from locally built html. URL for my locally built html file points to file:///C:/xampp/htdocs/api/currency-converter.html

Tags: javascript, html, webserver

I have placed the complete code here. can you please help why the URL in the browser is pointing to a local file (**file:///C:/xampp/htdocs/api/currency-converter.html**) instead of it being like (**http://localhost/api/currency-converter.html**). Also, help me to understand why I am not able to call the public API (*currency converter API*) to get the JSON response. I have replaced the API key with XXXX here.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Currency Converter</title>
    <style>
      * {
        font-family: cursive;
      }
      #container {
        height: 150px;
        margin: 0px auto;
      }
      h2 {
        font-size: 60px;
        text-align: center;
      }
      table {
        margin: 0px auto;
      }
      span {
        font-size: 30px;
      }
      input {
        font-size: 30px;
        border: 2px solid black;
        border-radius: 10px;
        text-align: center;
      }
      select {
        font-size: 30px;
        border: 2px solid black;
        border-radius: 10px;
      }
      #result {
        text-align: center;
        font-size: 50px;
        border-style: dashed;
      }
    </style>
    <script>
      function CurrencyConversion() {
        var fromvalue = document.getElementbyID("From").value;

        var tovalue = document.getElementbyID("To").value;

        var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

        var url =
          "http://api.exchangeratesapi.io/v1/latest?access_key=xxxxxxxxx&symbols=" +
          fromvalue +
          "," +
          tovalue;

        xmlhttp.open("GET", url, true);

        xmlhttp.send();

        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
          if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
            var result = xmlhttp.responseText;

            alert(result);
          }
        };
      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body onload="CurrencyConversion();">
    <div id="container">
      <h2>Currency Converter</h2>
      <table>
        <tr>
          <th><span>Amount</span></th>
          <th><span>From Currency</span></th>
          <th><span>To Currency</span></th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <input
              type="Number"
              id="FrmAmt"
              value="1"
              onkeyup="CurrencyConversion();"
            />
          </td>
          <td>
            <select id="From" onchange="CurrencyConversion()">
              <option value="USD" selected>US Dollar</option>
              <option value="INR">Indian Rupee</option>
            </select>
          </td>
          <td>
            <select id="To" onchange="CurrencyConversion();">
              <option value="USD">US Dollar</option>
              <option value="INR" selected>Indian Rupee</option>
            </select>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td colspan="3">
            <div id="result"></div>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason why it points to a local file is because the html file is not being hosted on localhost, but rather as a file you are opening on the browser locally. If you want the file to be hosted on localhost, you can use the `serve` module on npm, or if you are using an IDE there are probably extensions you can install to serve your project on localhost (eg. Live Server on vscode.)

As to why the API does not work, it is really hard of someone to read your code if its formatted so poorly. Please paste it so that the code is readable. However, I have a feeling it might have something to do with your CORS configuration.

Side note: you should sanitize user input before using it, your current configuration is trivially easy to execute a XSS attack on.